# exam: Converting number to string and capitalizing the result

Tags: formatting, exam, fmtcount

Here, `\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\numberstringnum\numpoints}` results in **one5** instead of **FIFTEEN**.

Additionally, the capitalization doesn't work for the rest of the elements (e.g. `\MakeUppercase{\numberstringnum\numquestions}` should give **TWO** instead of **two**.).

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{fmtcount}

\begin{document}
    This exam contains {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\numberstringnum\numquestions}} questions, {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\numberstringnum\numpages}} pages (including the cover) for the total of {\bfseries\MakeUppercase{\numberstringnum\numpoints}} marks.
    \begin{questions}
        \question[10] some question
        \question[5] another question
    \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following patch using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) ensures that you don't get any errors while still printing the number using a string. Additionally, it defines `\NAME`-companions for the three `\num`-macros, allowing you to still use the `\num`-macros elsewhere:

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage{fmtcount,etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\let\NAMEquestions\numquestions
\patchcmd{\NAMEquestions}{\exam@numquestions}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numquestions}}{}{}
\let\NAMEpages\numpages
\patchcmd{\NAMEpages}{\exam@lastpage}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@lastpage}}{}{}
\let\NAMEpoints\numpoints
\patchcmd{\NAMEpoints}{\exam@numpoints}{{\NUMBERstringnum\exam@numpoints}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This exam contains \textbf{\NAMEquestions} questions, 
  \textbf{\NAMEpages} pages (including the cover) 
  for a total of \textbf{\NAMEpoints} marks.

\begin{questions}
  \question[10] some question
  \question[5] another question
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

The use of `\MakeUppercase` is explicitly covered in the [`fmtcount`](//ctan.org/pkg/fmtcount) [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount/fmtcount.pdf), hence the definition of a `\NUMBERstring`/`\NUMBERstringnum` counterpart to `\numberstring`/`\numberstringnum`.

Comment: What if I would like to not permanently change these macros?, i.e. I would like to later use `\numquestions` to get `2` instead of **TWO**? So, can I create new macros and keep the original intact?

Comment: @Diaa: I've updated it to use `\NAME`-macros, leaving the `\num`-macros untouched.